# SQL/VBA Delete rows between two values

Tags: sql, vba, rows, between

What I want to do is delete all rows between 2 values. The first value is "Item Group" while the other value is "End of Item Group", so in the example below, "Kit/Package","Non-inventory Item" would be deleted. It isn't always "Kit/Package","Non-inventory Item" that is between Item Group and End of Item Group so I really want to stick to 2 values.

Not sure if it's better to work on Excel VBA or SQL.

I tried this query but it only deletes the line with Item Group and End of item group:

```
DELETE from test_backup
where Item_Type between 'Item Group' and 'End of Item Group'


Item_Type

Item Group
Kit/Package
Kit/Package
Non-inventory Item
End of Item Group

Item Group
Kit/Package
Kit/Package
Non-inventory Item
End of Item Group

Item Group
Kit/Package
Kit/Package
Non-inventory Item
End of Item Group
```

Comment: Sort your possible values alphabetically, and I think it will be pretty clear what's happening. K (Kit/Package) is not between 'E' (End of Item Group) and 'I' (Item Group).  Try `delete from ... where item_type not in ('Item Group', 'End of Item Group')`.

Comment: *Is* this in a database somewhere? If so, you'd probably be much better off normalizing it so that an "Item Group" was identifiable by a PK.